# Java to estimate DB table percent filled

Tags: java, database, metadata, resultset

I have a Oracle table with about 130 fields in it, all of varying types (VARCHARS, CHARS, NUMBERS etc.), representing post-mortem examinations of animals. It's a constantly editable table from a Java driven web form and I'm creating a preceding summary JSP table of the different PME's within the Oracle table (just PME-ID, creation-dt, vet name etc.). The vets will add to the table when they get info in on tests etc. over a period of weeks.

Is there anyway to use ResultSetMetaData or equivalent to gauge/measure how many of the fields have been populated, given the variety of data types that exist? I'd rather not have to deal with each field individually to work out if it's populated or not, as that would imply a big, fully specified loop to get a single summary value.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: populated = column in row (n) not equals `null`?

Comment: Yep, used 
while (records.next()) {
            for (int i = 1; i <= md.getColumnCount(); i++) {
                Object o = records.getObject(md.getColumnLabel(i));
                if (o != null) {
                    counter++;
                }
            }
        }
and that gave reasonable results. Thanks